# Excel - search part of a string, vlookup value in table

Tags: excel, string, range, match, vlookup

I have two tables in Excel :

In `table 1`, one column contains strings of data. The format is not structured but will always contain a keyword that I'm trying to match to a column in `table 2`. Example:

```
32984723987 BLA BLA &*& KEYWORD 232328 BLA
```

In `table 2`, the first column contains keywords. The second column  subcategory labels.

How can I use `vlookup` or another formula to fill in the matching subcategory from `table 2`, if a keyword exists in `table 1`?

I've been trying with range lookup, but I need to input some search criteria. But which one? I need to check against the entire column of keywords in `table 2`.

Edit: To be more clear:  the lookup_value needs to check whether part of the string (*the keyword*) of cell Sheet1!A1 exist anywhere in Sheet2!A1:A100 (the *entire* column of keywords). If it exists, the formula should return the value of Sheet2!Bx (the row number where the matched keyword was found).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use wildcards on your vlookup, for example:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&table2!A1&"*", table1!A:A, 1, FALSE)
```

Edit: do it with this VBA code (EDITED code)

```
Sub findKeywords()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim rWs, kWs As Worksheet
Dim dataColumn, targetColumn, keysColumn As Integer

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set rWs = wb.Sheets("rawSheet") 'this is the sheet your raw data is
Set kWs = wb.Sheets("keySheet") 'this is your sheet with the keys
dataColumn = 1 'this is the number of the column you will search
targetColumn = 2 'this is the number of the column you will insert the matched row
keysColumn = 1 'this is your column with the keywords you will look for

For Each r In rWs.Range(rWs.Cells(1, dataColumn).Address, rWs.Cells(rWs.Rows.Count, dataColumn).End(xlUp).Address)
    For i = 1 To kWs.Cells(kWs.Rows.Count, keysColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        If r.Value Like "*" & kWs.Cells(i, keysColumn).Value & "*" Then
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = kWs.Cells(i, keysColumn).Offset(0, 1).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks, but that won't do the trick. The lookup_value needs to check whether *part of the string* (the keyword) in Sheet1!A1 exist anywhere in Sheet2!A1:A100 (the *entire* column of keywords). If it exists, it should return the value of Sheet2!Bx (the row number where the matched keyword was found).

Comment: in this case you will need a vba solution, wait a little bit i can come up with one

Comment: Thanks to much. It fills the cells it should fill, but not with the expected values... In stead of returning the labels in column B of sheet2, it returns numbers, and the numbers do not correspond to the the row that matches the keyword. There seem to be a lot of 61, 69, 110, I don't know why. I feel the code is close, but not there yet. I'm not a programmer, so am unable to fix it. Any suggestions would be very welcome. Many thanks for your help so far!

Comment: ok, i'll try again, is there a way for you to put part of your content on a google sheet and share, so i can copy to my excel and adapt the code to your need?

Comment: ok, the code was first pickin a number because i thought you wanted the row of the keyword in sheet2, i just adjusted this part to get the value of the column B at keywords sheet. As for the rows not being correct, if you mean all rows I don't get why because it works here, but if it's just for keywords in certain rows, it's probably because they're small words and some address were matching them

Comment: to avoid this problem now the code gets only the first keyword match and then goes to search the next sheet1 value, so to work properly you should sort your keywords in order to have the the lengthy ones first and the small ones in the end, so for example "PRESSING" won't match to "PRESS" before find his correct match... that being said, please try the new code